# could not send mail using PHPMailer even after setting openssl in php.ini

Tags: php

i m having trouble with e-mail in php, i want mail to myself(just for a test), i want to use this feature so that users can mail me thier feedback from the site.

I have enabled the openssl in php.ini, i'm using wamp server 2.0 on localhost and win7
plzzz help me out i am new to php !!!
Here is the code:-

```
<?php
require('PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Host = 'mail.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'myid@gmail.com';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                   // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'myid@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'AshiMailer';
$mail->AddAddress('myid.sbit@gmail.com', 'Josh Adams');  // Add a recipient
$mail->AddAddress('myid@gmail.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->AddReplyTo('myid@gmail.com', 'Information');
//$mail->AddCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->AddBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
//$mail->AddAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//$mail->AddAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';

?>
```

Comment: So what is happening when you run? Any errors? Do you have a mail server installed? Is your smtp port settings right? Need more info to be able to help.

Comment: You don't see any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use these settings

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
```

Comment: @daker when i run this i get this error:-
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. (0)SMTP Connect() failed. Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP Connect() failed.

Comment: hey thanx @swapnil it worked this time, i tried that before too but it worked this time, thanx a lottt1 ^^

Comment: but now how do i hide all the info that i get on output screen??

CLIENT -> SMTP: EHLO localhost...<<<some more lines>>>... SMTP: This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail  SMTP: CLIENT -> SMTP: --b1_a0bde358a30c45222d4d85e3987c5982 CLIENT -> SMTP: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 CLIENT -> SMTP: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit CLIENT -> SMTP: CLIENT -> SMTP: This is the HTML message body in bold! CLIENT -> SMTP: CLIENT -> SMTP: CLIENT -> SMTP: CLIENT -> SMTP: --b1_a0bde358a30c45222d4d85e3987c5982-- CLIENT -> SMTP: CLIENT -> SMTP: . CLIENT -> SMTP: quit Message has been sent